# How to Map anonymous object in Auto Mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Am trying to Map an Anonymous object in auto mapper but am not getting how to do that. Please find my requirement below

Am getting some data from joining 2 tables with only one common column(Id). Am getting Anonymous type data from this query.

```
var query = (from _vdata in Table1
                  join entityFind in Table2 on _vdata.id equals entityFind.id
                  select new { entityFind.FamilyName, entityFind.LastLogin, entityFind.GivenName, 
                  entityFind.Email, entityFind.EmailVerified, entityFind.Uuid, _vdata.Role, 
                  _vdata.Payers, _vdata.Accounts, _vdata.ModifiedOn }).ToList();
```

Am getting Anonymous data from above query. I have some more list of data in another variable i need to add those data to this list with limited columns having 4-5 columns.

How to do mapping in this situation in AutoMapper or in any other technique

thanks

Comment: Don't. Add FK references where needed and use `ProjectTo`. No anonymous type needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since all anonymous types derived from System.Object, I found a solution (workaround) to add mapping from object to your destination type

```
            //Allow to map anonymous types to concrete type
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof(object), typeof(ExternalCandle), 
                MemberList.None);
```

**But please note that for most scenarios this is not the correct solution**
For example, if you want to map ORM types - go with this way: [Queryable Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard)

I guess that [Jimmy bogard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard) won't recommend this solution because of the same reason that CreateMissingTypeMaps was removed from AutoMappers's API -https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3063

So maybe in a future version of AutoMapper this code won't work (I am using AutoMapper 10.1.1 and it worked for me)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot map anonymous type. To achieve the above functionality you can create a Model like below:

```cs
public class ResultantData
{
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string LastLogin { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EmailVerified { get; set; }
    public string Uuid { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Payers { get; set; }
    public string Accounts { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write the above query as below and return the IQueryable of the result:

```
var query = (from _vdata in Table1
                         join entityFind in Table2 on _vdata.id equals entityFind.id
                         select new ResultantData
                         {
                             entityFind.FamilyName,
                             entityFind.LastLogin,
                             entityFind.GivenName,
                             entityFind.Email,
                             entityFind.EmailVerified,
                             entityFind.Uuid,
                             _vdata.Role,
                             _vdata.Payers,
                             _vdata.Accounts,
                             _vdata.ModifiedOn
                         });
```

When you want to map this result to actual model then you can use [ProjectTo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6) method of Automapper as below:

```
var result = query.ProjectTo<ResultantDataModel>().ToList();
```

I have used below class as result model:

```cs
public class ResultantDataModel
{
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string LastLogin { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string EmailVerified { get; set; }
    public string Uuid { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Payers { get; set; }
    public string Accounts { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's manual mapping. You can simply create the destination :)

Comment: But the user want separate POCO Entity and ViewModel. @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: That's irrelevant. You either map by hand, or you use AM. Doing both at the same time makes little sense.